# Aurora - Load data from s3 when bucket is encrypted

Tags: encryption, amazon-s3, amazon-kms, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to load data from a CSV file which is stored in an encrypted S3 bucket into an Aurora table.

```
LOAD DATA FROM S3 's3-eu-west-1://my.bucket/payout/export_payout.csv'
INTO TABLE payout
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(payment_block_key,doc_date, item_text, currency, @days_in_arrears)
SET
days_in_arrears = NULLIF(@days_in_arrears, '');
```

If i run this query i get the following error:

```
S3 API returned error: Access Denied:Access Denied
```

How do i specify the KMS key arn for downloading the file to aurora?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aurora uses an IAM Role to access data from Amazon S3. You will need to grant that role permission to access the S3 bucket and also permission to use the relevant key from KMS.

See:

- [Creating an IAM Policy to Access Amazon S3 Resources - Amazon Aurora](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Authorizing.IAM.S3CreatePolicy.html)
- [Creating an IAM Role to Allow Amazon Aurora to Access AWS Services - Amazon Aurora](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Authorizing.IAM.CreateRole.html)

Comment: Thx! This did the trick. I've added the `kms:Decrypt` action to my policy with the corresponding key as `Resource`. [This Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Authorizing.IAM.KMSCreatePolicy.html) took me to the solution.